# How can I get rid of my grub problem?

Tags: diagnosis, lawn, landscaping, grubs

I have lots of yellow/brown spots on my lawn, and I think they are caused by grubs. I would like to know:

1. How can I confirm that grubs are, in fact, the problem?
2. What products are available to combat this issue and make my lawn green again?

Comment: What part of the world are you in (pests differ in different countries/regions)? Can you add a photo of the lawn showing the yellow/brown spots please?

Comment: Good question; if could include illustrations, region, soil type, and nearby plants & trees etc could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!